# $2^x+2^y = 2^a+2^b$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $x,y$ be positive integers such that $x<y$. Does there exist another pair of integers $a,b$ with $a<b$ such that $(x,y),(y,x) \neq (a,b)$ and $2^x+2^y = 2^a+2^b$?

I was wondering if this was true but wasn't sure how to prove it. If it is true, can it be generalized?

Comment: I would write $2^x(1+2^{y-x})=2^a(1+2^{b-a})$ and by the fundamental theorem of arithmetica we must have $x=a$ (and $y=b$ follows).

Answer (score 3):

No. To see this informally, just consider the binary representations of $2^x+2^y$ and $2^a+2^b$. If $x\ne a$ or $y\ne b$, these numbers are clearly unequal.

Alternatively, assume $2^x+2^y = 2^a+2^b$. Suppose $x\le a$; then dividing both sides by $2^x$ gives $1+2^{y-x} = 2^{a-x}+2^{b-x}$. The left-hand side is odd since $x<y$; since also $x\le a<b$, the right-hand side is odd if and only if $a=x$. Then $2^{y-x} = 2^{b-x}$; it follows that $b=y$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose such a pair $(a,b)$ exists with $a<b$. In fact, $2^x+2^y-2^a=2^b$ by assumption. Let $m=\text{max}(x,y,a,b)$ and observe that dividing by $2^m$, we have 
$$ 2^{x-m}+2^{y-m}-2^{a-m}=2^{b-m}.$$ 
By assumption, $x\ne a$, and $y\ne b,$ so if $b-m=0$, then we have the left side even, while the right side is odd$^{\dagger}$. If any of the exponents on the left hand side equal $0$, we have the left hand side odd, while the right hand side is even. This shows that such a pair can not exist.

$\dagger$ The idea here is to show that only one of $x-m,y-m,a-m,b-m$ is equal to zero. This allows us to use the subsequent parity argument.

Answer (score 0):

Others have given the answers. I want to add a remark that this is still impossible if $2$ is replaced by any bigger integer $b$.
The interpretation is that expression of a number in any base is unique 
The general statement can be for more than  two terms:
$$b^x+b^y= b^r+ b^s$$ But when we have more than 2 terms we can allow repetition of indices but any repetition should be less than $b$

That is a representation  $n=\sum_{i=0}^k c_ib^i$ with $0\le c_i<b$ is unique.